# Таблицы html, вывод данных из бд в таблицу php

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin

Когда я пытался вывести данные из таблицы в бд,  в таблицу на странице сайта, то столкнулся нос в нос с проблемой вывода т.к. табличку я создал не совсем стандартную

```
<table> <tr> <td>запись1</td> <td>запись2</td> <td>запись3</td> <td>запись4</td> <tr> </table>
```

Таблица моя состоит из нескольких строк(не суть сколько) и 4 колонок (вот с ними и проблема)

Задача состоит в том, что надо вывести все данные из таблицы БД в таблицу на странице поочередно(как бы списком, но в виде таблицы) (схематичный рисунок прикрепил)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я пытаюсь вывести значения так:

```
    <table>
         <?php   
         require 'lib/connect.php';

            // SQL-запрос
            $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY date DESC";

            // Выполнить запрос (набор данных $rs содержит результат)
            $rs = mysql_query($strSQL);

            // Цикл по recordset $rs
            // Каждый ряд становится массивом ($row) с помощью функции mysql_fetch_array
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {

               // Записать значение столбца FirstName (который является теперь массивом $row)

        echo"<tr>";
               echo "<tr>";
        echo"".$row['znachenie']."";
              echo"".$row['znachenie']."";
              echo"".$row['znachenie']."";
 echo"".$row['znachenie']."";
        echo"</td>";



              echo"</tr>";

            mysql_close();
        }    ?> </table>
```

Но тут получается так, что все первая строка таблицы равняется повторяющемуся одному значению, как же сделать так, чтобы значения были поочерёдные, например может надо приписать к  `echo"".$row['znachenie']."";` скобку `[]` с чем-то внутри?

Comment: дак, а что просто напросто в цсс не приставить grid или flex wrap и ширину нужную?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Первый вариант:

```
<?php
    $arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
    echo "<tr>";
    $idx = 1;
    foreach($arr as $value) {
        printf("<td>%s</td>", $value);
        if ($idx%4 === 0) {
            echo "</tr><tr>";
        }

        $idx++;
    }
    echo "</tr>";
```

Второй вариант:

Использовать что то типа 
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

```
<?php
    $arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
    echo "<div class='row'>";
    foreach($arr as $value) {
        // по 12
        //printf("<div class='col-md-1'>%s</div>", $value);
        // по 6
        //printf("<div class='col-md-2'>%s</div>", $value);
        // по 4
        printf("<div class='col-md-3'>%s</div>", $value);
        // по 3
        //printf("<div class='col-md-4'>%s</div>", $value);
        // по 2
        //printf("<div class='col-md-6'>%s</div>", $value);
    }

    echo "</div>";
```

**ПС:** Самое главное перестаньте мешать представление и логику. Посмотрите на шаблонизаторы.

Comment: Странно, почему-то пишет к первому варианту, что ошибка(((

Comment: Не грузит страницу, хотя сервер работает нормально(

Comment: Спасибо вам (галочку поставил :), только я решил использовать не бустрап, а создал простенькую сетку на css и всё заработало, так бы не додумался))))) :-)

Answer (score 1):

Для MDB (продвинутый по дизайну вариант Bootstrap)
https://mdbootstrap.com

Создаём БД "company" с таблицей "userinfo" и 
столбцами: 
userinfo_id, userinfo_name, userinfo_position,    userinfo_region,userinfo_age,userinfo_begin_date

ещё нужно CSS подключать

```
<!-- MDBootstrap Datatables  -->
  <link href="css/addons/datatables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Вводим в тело файла, для продвинутой таблицы:

```
<table id="dtMaterialDesignExample" class="table table-striped" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="th-sm">№
      </th>
      <th class="th-sm">Ф.И.О.
      </th>
      <th class="th-sm">Должность
      </th>
      <th class="th-sm">Область
      </th>
      <th class="th-sm">Возраст
      </th>
      <th class="th-sm">Начало работа
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

  <?php 
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "company"); 
    // Check connection 
    if ($conn->connect_error) { 
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error); 
    }  
    $sql = "SELECT userinfo_id, userinfo_name, userinfo_position,
    userinfo_region,userinfo_age,userinfo_begin_date 
    FROM userinfo"; 

    $result = $conn->query($sql); 
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) { 

      // output data of each row 
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { 

      echo "<tr><td>" . $row["userinfo_id"]
        . "</td><td>" . $row["userinfo_name"] 
        . "</td><td>" . $row["userinfo_position"]
        . "</td><td>" . $row["userinfo_region"]
        . "</td><td>" . $row["userinfo_age"]
        . "</td><td>" . $row["userinfo_begin_date"]
        . "</td></tr>"; 
    } 
    echo "</tbody>";

    } else { echo "0 results"; } 
    $conn->close(); 
  ?>
```

и Java скрипт

```
// Material Design example
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#dtMaterialDesignExample').DataTable();
    $('#dtMaterialDesignExample_wrapper').find('label').each(function () {
    $(this).parent().append($(this).children());
    });
    $('#dtMaterialDesignExample_wrapper .dataTables_filter').find('input').each(function () {
    $('input').attr("placeholder", "Search");
    $('input').removeClass('form-control-sm');
    });
    $('#dtMaterialDesignExample_wrapper .dataTables_length').addClass('d-flex flex-row');
    $('#dtMaterialDesignExample_wrapper .dataTables_filter').addClass('md-form');
    $('#dtMaterialDesignExample_wrapper select').removeClass(
    'custom-select custom-select-sm form-control form-control-sm');
    $('#dtMaterialDesignExample_wrapper select').addClass('mdb-select');
    $('#dtMaterialDesignExample_wrapper .mdb-select').materialSelect();
    $('#dtMaterialDesignExample_wrapper .dataTables_filter').find('label').remove();
    });
```

ещё нужно JS подключать

```
<!-- MDBootstrap Datatables  -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/addons/datatables.min.js"></script>
```